# Assign Names based on total in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes in which first data frame is **Problems** it has problem number and number of problem to be solved, second data frame is **Name_Data** it is having name of the person who will solve the problems and days for which he can work. I need the resulting data frame such as based on total person and days availability, problem list will be assigned to each person. Problem_Solver_Name has to be assigned equally by calculating total problems divided by days availability of problem solver. Problem_with_Solver is my resulting data frame.

Please help if anybody has the solution for this

```
Name=c("Antony","Roger","Peter","Samuel")
Days=c(1,1,0.5,1)
Name_Data=data.frame(Name,Days)

Problem_List=c("Problem1","Problem2","Problem3","Problem4","Problem5","Problem6","Problem7","Problem8",
               "Problem9","Problem10","Problem11","Problem12","Problem13","Problem14","Problem15","Problem16",
               "Problem17","Problem18","Problem19")
Total_Problem=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21)
Problems=data.frame(Problem_List,Total_Problem)

Problem_Solver_Name=c("Antony","Antony","Antony","Antony","Antony","Antony","Roger","Roger","Roger","Roger","Roger","Peter","Peter","Peter","Samuel","Samuel","Samuel","Samuel","Samuel")
Problem_with_Solver=data.frame(Problem_List,Total_Problem,Problem_Solver_Name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.
First assign names proportionally to the days availability, then fill the remaining needs running through all names while there still are problems needing a solver's name.
This last assignment criterion is probably not the best but it will end up assigning names to problems.

```r
# Persons availability data
Name <- c("Antony","Roger","Peter","Samuel")
Days <- c(1,1,0.5,1)
Name_Data <- data.frame(Name, Days)

# Problems data
Problem_List <- c("Problem1","Problem2","Problem3","Problem4","Problem5","Problem6","Problem7","Problem8",
                  "Problem9","Problem10","Problem11","Problem12","Problem13","Problem14","Problem15","Problem16",
                  "Problem17","Problem18","Problem19")
Total_Problem <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18,19,20,21)
Problems <- data.frame(Problem_List, Total_Problem)


#
# X: person and days availability data
#
assign_solver <- function(X, Problems, Solver) {
  N <- nrow(Problems)
  tt <- N * X$Days
  nn <- N * tt / sum(tt)
  #
  # psn: problem solver name
  psn <- character(N)
  psn[1:sum(round(nn))] <- rep(X$Name, round(nn))
  k <- 1L + sum(round(nn))
  i <- 1L
  while(k <= N) {
    psn[k] <- X$Name[i]
    i <- if(i < nrow(X)) i + 1L else 1L
    k <- k + 1L
  }
  psn <- psn[order(match(psn, X$Name))]
  psn
}

Problem_with_Solver <- data.frame(Problem_List, Total_Problem)
Problem_with_Solver$Problem_Solver_Name <- assign_solver(Name_Data, Problems, Problem_Solver_Name)
Problem_with_Solver
#>    Problem_List Total_Problem Problem_Solver_Name
#> 1      Problem1             1              Antony
#> 2      Problem2             2              Antony
#> 3      Problem3             3              Antony
#> 4      Problem4             4              Antony
#> 5      Problem5             5              Antony
#> 6      Problem6             6              Antony
#> 7      Problem7             8               Roger
#> 8      Problem8             9               Roger
#> 9      Problem9            10               Roger
#> 10    Problem10            11               Roger
#> 11    Problem11            12               Roger
#> 12    Problem12            13               Peter
#> 13    Problem13            14               Peter
#> 14    Problem14            15               Peter
#> 15    Problem15            16              Samuel
#> 16    Problem16            18              Samuel
#> 17    Problem17            19              Samuel
#> 18    Problem18            20              Samuel
#> 19    Problem19            21              Samuel
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>